# Application terminates when FirebaseAuth.getInstance() returns "null"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am starting with Firebase and I was going through this recently posted tutorial online.

At one point we have to start the application and there is this bit of code:

```
// Initialize Firebase Auth
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
    // Not logged in, launch the Log In activity
    loadLogInView();
}
```

This is placed in the `onCreate()`. The issue is that whenever I try to run the application, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null` for line 28 which is `mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Why am I getting `null`? And apart from that, what prevents the application from running despite that I am getting `null`? I am already treating the `null` in a way anyway.

The code never reaches the next line, it just stops at getting the Auth instance.

Comment: Have you copied the google_services.json file to the /app directory?

Comment: @DinukaJayasuriya yes, I did. i tried removing it/moving it somewhere else, the build fails miserably, so I presume this is all good.

Comment: Maybe you could show the entire stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @DougStevenson Well, the issue is now fixed. The way it worked is I opened up the AS assistant, went through the Firebase connections process. 

The issue got resolved when the assistant RE-applied the dependencies in the Gradle file and synced. The thing is that I had tried re-applying them and re-syncing like 10 times before that.. Probably a bug in AS? 

Any suggestions what to do with this SO question now? :(

Comment: Not sure what to say here.  Maybe your project was just in a bad state.  :-/  I've not used the assistant very much, and it's new, so maybe there are problems with it.

Comment: Devil is  `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Go to project level `build.gradle` & check if it looks exactly like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

and the code suddenly works and when you'll look at other answers you will find the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about this, but i believe your mFireBaseAuth is not initialised yet. Maybe.

I guess this because I read in firebase docs : 
Note: getCurrentUser might also return null because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use a listener to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your app `Gradle` file. And please make sure that the following line is added at the bottom

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If this line is missing, then your code will compile fine, but `FirebaseAuth`will fail to instantiate/initialize without reasonable warning.

Another possibility could be that your Authentication is not properly enabled in the Firebase Console. Please enable accordingly. Screenshot attached.
[image]

All the best!

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I set this in the  Module:app file but I still get a null object - the google_services.json file is in place as well.

Comment: @kilokahn - Hi, can you post a screenshot of the module:app where you have put this statement? The position is also important.

Comment: @kilokahn - I have updated my answer with the Screenshot. Please check in your Firebase Console that at least one of the authentication methods are 'enabled' .Looking at your code it should be "Email/Password" or "Phone" because others will need more additions to your module:app gradle files.

Comment: Got that. It was enabled but I had not added the <activity> with android:name in the manifest. The null was because the activity couldnt be loaded. Thanks so much for the assist though! :)